# Возможно ли реализовать двойные команды в Node.js CLI-приложении?

Tags: node.js, консоль

Я только что закончил [этот урок](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js) по созданию Node.js CLI. Я узнал, как создавать новые cli-команды с параметрами, например `my-cli-command --parameter`.

А что, если я хочу, чтобы моё приложение делало несколько вещей? В приведённом выше уроке приложение умеет делать только одно - разворачивать проект, однако оно не умеет, например, собирать проект или деполоить его.

Разумеется, желаемую задачу можно передать в виде параметра:

```
my-cli --doSomething1
my-cli --doSomething2
```

Но что-то как-то не элегантно наличие глагола в параметре. Куда лучше выглядело бы:

```
my-cli doSomething1 --otherParameter
my-cli doSomething2 --otherParameter
```

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: Например, https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:cli в топе выдаёт yargs https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Получается, на нативном Node.js эта задача трудно решаема?

Comment: В смысле? Этот пакет написан на «нативном» node.js

Comment: Я имел ввиду "без библиотек".

Comment: Да никаких проблем. Просто зачем, если уже есть готовое? Если для самообразования, то почитайте код

Comment: Ну, тут уже чистый холивар сторонников и противников библиотек, поэтому не будем тратить душевные силы на пустые споры :)

Answer (score 1):

Приведённый ниже код из этого же урока. Массив `args._` (всегда существует, но может быть пустым) содержит все подкоманды (не только двойные).

```
import arg from 'arg';

function parseArgumentsIntoOptions(rawArgs) {
 const args = arg(
   {
     '--git': Boolean,
     '--yes': Boolean,
     '--install': Boolean,
     '-g': '--git',
     '-y': '--yes',
     '-i': '--install',
   },
   {
     argv: rawArgs.slice(2),
   }
 );
 return {
   skipPrompts: args['--yes'] || false,
   git: args['--git'] || false,
   template: args._[0],
   runInstall: args['--install'] || false,
 };
}
```